# Convert Fortran DO WHILE loop to Python

Tags: python, while-loop, fortran

I am trying to convert the following Fortran loop to python. The objective is to set `abs(ETP-ET)=0.0`. However, my solution doesn't converge to 0.0. What´s wrong in my approach?

Fortran code

```
ET(I)   =  TDEW_F
  TSTAR   = (ET(I)+TDEW_F)*0.5
  BETA    =  0.255-(8.5E-3*TSTAR)+(2.04E-4*TSTAR*TSTAR)
  FW      =  ACONV*AFW(JW)+BCONV*BFW(JW)*WIND2M**CFW(JW)
  CSHE(I) =  15.7+(0.26+BETA)*FW
  RA      =  3.1872E-08*(TAIR_F+459.67)**4
  ETP     = (SRO_BR+RA-1801.0)/CSHE(I)+(CSHE(I)-15.7)*(0.26*TAIR_F+BETA*TDEW_F)/(CSHE(I)*(0.26+BETA))
  J       =  0
  DO WHILE (ABS(ETP-ET(I)) > 0.05 .AND. J < 10)
    ET(I)   =  ETP
    TSTAR   = (ET(I)+TDEW_F)*0.5
    BETA    =  0.255-(8.5E-3*TSTAR)+(2.04E-4*TSTAR*TSTAR)
    CSHE(I) =  15.7+(0.26+BETA)*FW
    ETP     = (SRO_BR+RA-1801.0)/CSHE(I)+(CSHE(I)-15.7)*(0.26*TAIR_F+BETA*TDEW_F)/(CSHE(I)*(0.26+BETA))
    J       =  J+1
  END DO

RETURN
```

Python code

```
ET = TDEW_F
TSTAR = (ET+TDEW_F)*0.5
BETA  =  0.255-(8.5E-3*TSTAR)+(2.04E-4*TSTAR*TSTAR)
FW = ACONV*AFW(JW)+BCONV*BFW(JW)*WIND2M**CFW(JW)
CSHE = 15.7+(0.26+BETA)*FW
RA = 3.1872E-08*(AirT_F+459.67)**4
ETP = (SRO_BR+RA-1801.0)/CSHE+(CSHE-15.7)*(0.26*AirT_F+BETA*DewPt_F)/(CSHE*(0.26+BETA))

j = 0
while True:
    ET = ETP
    TSTAR = (ET+TDEW_F)*0.5
    BETA = 0.255-(8.5E-3*TSTAR)+(2.04E-4*TSTAR*TSTAR)
    CSHE = 15.7+(0.26+BETA)*FW
    ETP = (SRO_BR+RA+RA-1801.0)/CSHE+(CSHE-15.7)*(0.26*AirT_F+BETA*TDEW_F)/(CSHE*(0.26+BETA))

    j+=1
    if abs(ETP-ET) < 0.05 and j>10:
        break

    OUT = (ET-ETP)
    return OUT
```

Comment: `while True` cannot be equivalent to a loop that has a conditional check (unless your condition is obtuse And can never be satisfied)

Comment: `return OUT` in a loop inconditionally doesn't work

Comment: I do not see a reason why not just follow the Fortran as closely as possible. The whole `while True` thing seems unnecessary confusing to me. If Fortran has a conditional in the loop, just do the same in Python `while (condition):`. Also, in Fortran, even when you do not see the necessary declarations, `ET` appears to be an array. Why don't you keep it an array in Python? Really, just follow the original as closely as possible. It should be fairly straightforward, there is no difficult stuff in this code. It is the same in many programming languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `if abs(ETP-ET) < 0.05 and j>10:` with `if abs(ETP-ET) < 0.05 or j>10:` and remove indentation in `return OUT` so it is out of the while loop.